# Как лучше обособить приложения?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть два приложения: Институт такой-то, уполномоченная компания такая то, презентовала на экспозиции...

Как лучше обособить, запятыми или двумя тире?

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте две запятые или два тире. И тот и другой знаки укажут на обособленное приложение. Я бы поставила запятые.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос - то есть, институт относится к какой-то компании, то, думаю, уместно было бы обособить "компанию" скобками. Тире, в принципе, тоже возможно, но, если текст официальный, думаю, скобки будут уместнее.

Comment: Нет, здесь институт и компания - это одно и то же.